# Python - Move line from one file to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to read a text file, copy each line to a new file, and delete that line from the original file.  Not sure how to delete the line.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code so far:

```
    with open("TestList_in.txt",'r+') as f:
        for lineNum in f:
            lineNum.replace("\n","")
            with open("TestList_done.txt","a") as done:
                done.write(lineNum)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this?If you delete each line in the document you will finish with an empty file. If that is the case, I would recommend to delete the original file and create an empty file with the name of the original one.

Comment: The purpose is so that I can create multiple threads, all pulling from the same text file.  The file is a list of URLs.  If this isn't the best way, please let me know what would work better.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of creating threads all working from the same text file it wasn't necessary to delete each line as it was read.  Instead, importing the queue module and putting the lines in the queue worked.

```
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()

with open("TestList_in.csv",'r+') as f:
    for lineNum in f:
        q.put(lineNum)
        with open("TestList_done.txt","a") as done:
            newLine = q.get()
            done.write(newLine)
```